# How to create JIRA Project using java?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-java-api

How to create JIRA Project using java API for automation. ? Any Reference api documents also highly help.

Answer (score 0):

There exist REST API for JIRA see this link as [example](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/rest-apis/)

As I see they deprecate SOAP and XML-RPC API's check this [updates](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/)

Also good point to read and search is: [JIRA 7.6.1](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/)